# Stop visual studio from including a file when checking-in to team foundation server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am working in a group project in visual studio and I need to check-in my work every once in a while to Team Foundation Server. However there are some files in the project that I don't need to check-in to the server and I have to manually exclude them each time I check-in. How do I include some files or even a project into a permanent no include list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`.tfignore`](https://blog.appliedis.com/2014/11/06/excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files/) file (VS is a bit variable in picking up changes to this file, it doesn't seem to apply changes to files that are already pending changes). This uses the same format as `.gitignore`.